# How to get text from Span with Selenium Webdriver using Java

Tags: java, html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get a text value from a span element:

```
<td class="cs data">
<span id="ctl00_wnCore_ctlRiskDetails_ctdRiskDetails_rptCommon2Column_ctl01_lblValue">US00002277EQ15A</span>
</td>
```

I need to get the text value: US00002277EQ15A (or whatever this value happens to be) but none of the following examples work, they always return "N/A"

Example 1

```
String policyNumber =   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='ctl00_wnCore_ctlRiskDetails_ctdRiskDetails_rptCommon2Column_ctl01_lblValue']")).getAttribute("innerHTML");

System.out.println(policyNumber);
```

Example 2

```
String policyNumber =   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@id='ctl00_wnCore_ctlRiskDetails_ctdRiskDetails_rptCommon2Column_ctl01_lblValue']")).getText();
```

Example 3

```
String policyNumber =   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body form#aspnetForm div#canvas div#main div#rhs div#main_content div.client.aspx.transactionsummary div.core.ascx.products.riskdetails div.core.ascx.products.commontabledisplay div#ctl00_wnCore_ctlRiskDetails_ctdRiskDetails_divTwoColumnDisplay table.stdtable tbody tr#trAlternatingItemTemplate td.c2.data span#ctl00_wnCore_ctlRiskDetails_ctdRiskDetails_rptCommon2Column_ctl01_lblValue")).getText();
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: When you were writing your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with helpful formatting hints, an entire toolbar of formatting controls, a **[?]** button for more help, and a preview area underneath where you could see the results. Please take the time to use them.

Comment: Did you end your span tag?

Comment: It's working now.  Please ignore this post.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the text using javascript

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
String text=(String)executor.executeScript("return document.getElementById("enter span id"));
```

Tell me whether it works